# How to read text files in a folder and and save in an excel file

Tags: excel, python-3.x, operating-system, xlwt

I have numerous text files in one folder. Each text file has two values that are written in separate lines (using \n\ in .write function). It looks like the following.

```
0.907831
0.992549
```

I want to create one master excel file that has all of the values in my text files combined (rather than manually entering them).

The desired output would look like the following.

```
'Filename' 0.907831 0.992549
```

So far, I have the following code.

```
import xlwt
import os
import fnmatch

path='Z:\Data\13-output'
wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet('data')
row = 0


for files in os.walk(path):
     for file in files:
         if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
             L = open(os.path.join( file), "r").read()
             sheet.write(row,5,L)
             row += 1

wbk.save('all_values_in_txt.xls')
```

It does generate the excel file named, '`all_values_in_txt.xls`'. However, the excel sheet is blank. Any idea on how I can improve/fix the code?

Edit 1 (fixed by changing fnmatch to fnmatch.fnmatch): I realized I had some issues with following error, `if fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):` `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Edit 2:  I am now running into new errors

```
  File "<ipython-input-81-ddeb0284f378>", line 17, in <module>
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):

  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Anaconda3\lib\fnmatch.py", line 34, in fnmatch
    name = os.path.normcase(name)

  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 48, in normcase
    s = os.fspath(s)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Comment: Have you put in any debugging code to see what data you are reading in?

Comment: Hi, I get the following error,    `if fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):`

`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: Sure thing. just incorporated it in the post.

Comment: You should be using `if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt')` - that is causing the type error

Comment: @ialarmedalien, Thanks for the suggestion. It makes sense. Now the same line is not giving me a problem anymore.

Comment: what is the status of this question? have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just based on some very light testing, this seems like it should work for you.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\your_path_here\")

' set the starting point to write the data to
'Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sh = ActiveSheet

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
    ' Write file-name
    LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("A" & LastRow).Select
    ActiveCell = file.Name

    ' open the file
    Set txtFile = fso.OpenTextFile(file)

    col = 2
    Do While Not txtFile.AtEndOfStream
        dat = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(Split(txtFile.ReadLine, ","), 1, 0))
        sh.Cells(LastRow, col).Resize(UBound(dat), 1) = dat
        col = col + 1
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    txtFile.Close
    'Range(cl.Address).Offset(1, 0).Select
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Notice, you need to run this from a Module in Excel.

Comment: Yeap and I know he tagged Excel.  I'm constantly baffled by how many times I see people trying to do things that are infinitely harder than things could be done, if you use the right tool for the job.